# Incompatible block pointer types - sd_setImageWithUrl

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've been trying to figure this out for the past hour and after endless searching can't seem to see the issue. I'm new to Objective-C development and have recently taken on a new codebase to use as a learning tool.

I'm trying to set an image to a cell which has a placeholder image and upon a completed request, sets the image to the bounds of the cell. However the code is failing because of the following error:

**Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^)(UIImage *__strong, NSError *__strong, SDImageCacheType)'**

Upon searching SO and other sources all I can find is ensuring that void is indeed returned. You can see from the code below that nothing is returned, thus it *is* void.

```
if(imageURL != nil)
{
    cell.productImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
    __weak typeof(cell) weakCell = cell;
    [cell.productImageView sd_setImageWithURL:imageURL placeholderImage:[UIImage sd_animatedGIFNamed:@"loading-indicator"] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished) {
        if (image)
        {
            [weakCell.productImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
        }
    }];
}
```

Here is the header code for that particular item:

```
- (void)sd_setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholder completed:(SDWebImageCompletionBlock)completedBlock;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest API of SDWebImage is slightly different so change your code for this one:

```
if(imageURL != nil)
{
    cell.productImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
    __weak typeof(cell) weakCell = cell;
    [cell.productImageView sd_setImageWithURL:imageURL placeholderImage:[UIImage sd_animatedGIFNamed:@"loading-indicator"] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
        if (image)
        {
            [weakCell.productImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: @rossytzoltan could you mark answer as correct one please?

Comment: yep, I had to wait 4 minutes apparently.